# Is there a Java library that enables gathering UI usage statistics?

Tags: java, usage-statistics

Is there a Java library that enables gathering UI usage statistics?

Something that feels like log4j?

Comment: What kind of UI are you speaking of?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with the Eclipse plateform you might have a look on the Usage Data Collector project:

http://www.eclipse.org/epp/usagedata/

Comment: this one is not very useful for me - "At present, the UDC does not expose any official APIs, though there are several under consideration."- but still thank's for help

Answer (score 0):

I answered [this questio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511637/record-the-user-interaction-log4j?answertab=active#tab-top)n before I saw yours.

Specifically, I would point you at the
[NetBeans Platform Gesture Collection Infrastructure](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-gesture.html).

Although planning to use it, I have not yet, but it is much more mature than the Eclipse Usage Data Collector project listed here.

Porting a generic Swing project to the NetBeans Platform is not too hard, can be done piecemeal, and there are a number of examples (just google "porting swing project to netbeans").  If you decide to go this route, see [this tutorial](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/guide_for_porting_swing_applications).  Geertjan has some other blog entries on porting (and just about every other topic).